# Traversing a polymorphic finite binary tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

I have the following data type for my tree.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving ( Show )
```

I'd like to print a representation of a given tree using a left to right depth first traversal.

For the moment, I've decided to go with pattern matching.

```
showt :: Tree a -> [Char]
showt ( Leaf a ) = [a]
...
```

When I try to run it using GHCi, here's the error I get

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          showt :: forall a. Tree a -> [Char]
        at 2016.hs:31:10
    • In the expression: a
      In the expression: [a]
      In an equation for ‘showt’: showt (Leaf a) = [a]
    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: a (bound at 2016.hs:32:14)
        showt :: Tree a -> [Char] (bound at 2016.hs:32:1)
```

I don't see where the problem comes from. Haskell should infer the type, no?

Comment: `[a]` has type `[a]` while `showt` need to return a `[Char]`. You need to add a `Show` constraint on `a` and use `show` to convert values into strings: `showt :: Show a => Tree a -> [Char]`.

Comment: Yes, Haskell infers a type. And then it looks at the type you demanded (by writing `showt :: Tree a -> [Char]`) and checks whether the two types are compatible. They're not. You can fix your demand, or remove it and use the inferred type, or fix your implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is **not** because a `data Tree a = ... deriving Show`, that it means that `a` is a `Char`.

It only means that Haskell has *automatically* added an type instance:

```
instance Show a => Show (Tree a) where
    -- ...
```

So as you can see, it adds a type constraint: `a` must be an instance of `Show` in order for `Tree a` to be an instance of `Show`. So our first conclusion is **`a` can still be of any type**.

Furthermore, even if `a` is an instance of `Show`, it does **not** mean that it is a `String` (or `Char`). It only means that there are some functions available like `show :: (Show a) => a -> String`.

So there some options here:

- you add a type constraint, and use `show`:

  ```
  showt :: Show a => Tree a -> [Char]
  showt ( Leaf a ) = show a
  --- ...
  ```
- you restrict yourself to trees of type `String` (or type `Char`):

  ```
  showt :: Tree Char -> [Char]
  showt ( Leaf a ) = [a]
  --- ...
  ```

Finally Haskell *can* infer the type of a function, but here you provide an *explicit* type signature. If you however omit the signature, you let Haskell derive it automatically:

```
Prelude> let showt ( Leaf a ) = [a]
Prelude> :t showt
showt :: Tree t -> [t]
```